# Is beauty universal?

Tags: evolution

I don't know if this is off topic at all, but there are a lot of things that humans tend to consider beautiful which other animals in nature also seem attracted to. For example, bees pollinate the most vibrant flowers. Birds of Paradise appear to demonstrate a selective advantage to looking pretty. Peacocks flaunt their looks. Songbirds sing beautiful melodies. Butterflies are amazing. Some spider species have bright colors and perform cute dances. It seems like these examples demonstrate an evolutionary advantage not just for things that stick out from a crowd but also that look good to us humans.

So I guess my question is, is beauty universal? Are there aesthetic characteristics that are attractive to all these different kinds of animals, that would signal something good for others to see, and that different animals including humans would universally recognize as being nice?

Comment: There's plenty of things that have evolved that are considered ugly by humans. Cherry picking examples allows one to make virtually any argument seem reasonable. Voting to close as primarily opinion based because beauty is entirely subjective and individual so can't be reasonably discussed in an answer.

Comment: Not only on visual data; other-sorts of informations (Smell, Taste, Touch etc) could be beautiful (attractive in more general) or ugly/terrible (repulsive  in more general). And they are also vary from individual to individual. For say I can't imagine eat any rotten meat it smells so ugly, but a crow (*Corvus* sp.) grabs it joyfully.

Answer (score 3):

**Fitness**

Fitness is a trait which, when high is pretty much always attractive to potential mates in all species. However, fitness is definitely not an "aestetic characteristic".

**Traits that are often correlated with fitness**

There are some "aestetic characteristics" that are correlated to fitness in many species, such as body weight. Such trait are therefore often correlated with what individuals find appealing.

Body weight is a standard examples. Heavier individuals often have better competitive abilities, better foraging abilities and therefore have a higher fitness. As a consequence body weight is often used a s a proxy for fitness.

**Relative body characteristics**

Novel traits in a population can be evidence of parasitism and therefore would tend to be considered as non-attractive. However, counter to this intuition, it has been shown typically in birds having high sexual selection, that individuals having novel traits are more attractive.

**Why is there a lack of generalization?**

To build the intuition I would just say that given the gigantic phenotypic diversity that exist among all species that perform some level of mate choice, it is pretty clear that you will not find a simple morphological trait that will be attractive to all species.

Mating preferences evolves. Individuals that are attracted toward individuals that will yield to a high progeny (and low sexual conflict and low transmission of parasites) have higher fitness their preferences increase in frequency in the population. As a consequence, individuals like whatever is (should rather say 'was') favoured in the population. Now, in some population individuals are selected to be small, or to be big or any other things. This is the process of natural selection applied to mating preferences.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're referring to as "beauty" is completely subjective.  You say Birds of Paradise look pretty; I think otherwise.  I happen to find California Condors extremely attractive!  ;)

Cultural studies in humans show that what females view as sexy or attractive in one culture can be completely different from another.  The only common denominator seems to be an attraction towards *symmetry in faces*.  This has been shown by several studies in humans, but I don't know if it has ever been repeated in animals of different species.

Also different species of bees or other pollinators are attracted to different colors and smells in flowers.  They can be very selective.  Some species have a close relationship with and will only visit flowers of a single species, like the Yucca moth for example.  This again proves that "beauty" is subjective and that nothing is universally attractive.  Flowers that are visited by many species are not seen as more "beautiful."  They simply smell better, or have more nectar, or are easier to access.  I don't think there's any such thing as "beauty" in nature.  It's just an artificial label we have created...

Hope this helps!  :)

Comment: I agree with what you said. But I guess what I meant was if there is a hint of anything that inherently looks or sounds a certain way that is beautiful. I mean we can do the same thing about art, some people will say abstract art is good and others say there must be classical rules that are followed. And I for one am wholly unconvinced that abstract and classical just come down to taste, but I fear I'm veering too far into the philosophical. But maybe you can think of my question as, does nature have any "classical rules" of art that cause an above-average attraction.

Comment: Maybe I would find your answer more compelling if you demonstrated that random variation mixed with symmetry would produce the same type of ugly, normal, and beautiful distribution as what nature produces, and that then it'd be reasonable to say that we just pick out the brightly colored nice looking animals as beautiful because we coincidentally find them as nice as members of those species do (despite the near lack of colorful things in our own species). Oh, and maybe you like how vultures look more than birds of paradise, but overall people Indeed like the way the colorful birds look more.

Answer (score 2):

"Is beauty universal" is a question that is haunting the scientists, philosophers, psychologists and common people for a long time. Some of them consider beauty as a subjective feeling whereas a second group of people consider it universal. Both of them have reasons to believe.

So I would try to discuss the topic in an evidence based way rather than expressing my own opinion about it.

**Reasons to believe beauty is subjective** -
The subjective nature of beauty in human beings is very easy to acknowledge. Here are some common examples -

1. Culture - Surma and Mursi women in Ethiopia wearing large lip-plate (clay or wooden plates inserted in upper or lower lip) and long necked women in Myanmar are considered to be **beautiful** in their respective cultures. Some cultures **prefer** black skin whereas most western people prefer white skin color.
2. Gender - a good looking man is considered more **handsome** to a woman that to another man. Same is true for females also.
3. Individual - individual perception of **beauty** is most diverse among all of these. What seems **beautiful** to me may not be so to you (I think this doesn't need further elaboration).
4. Specific groups - a mother finds her children **beautiful** even if it has some deformity.
5. Other species - sometimes it becomes confusing to differentiate the perception of **beauty** with other feelings in human and other animals. I am taking the examples you provided "Peacocks flaunt their looks." - the colorful feathers looks **beautiful** to most human beings. But it is actually a method to attract sexual attention of peahens (Courtship dance). Sexual attraction is a different feeling from **beauty**. 
   If the peacock example feels confusing to you, just take another easy example - most of us feel attracted to chocolates, but we may not consider it **beautiful**...so they are two separate feelings, right !
   We love flowers, they are **beautiful**. But if you give a flower to a goat to admire its beauty it would at once put the flower into its mouth not even bothering to give it a glance.
6. Some things we feel **beautiful** may no have developed for that purpose at all. Tigers and zebras have those **beautiful** branding on their body to help them hide in grass field with two completely different purpose (one is predator and the other is a prey)
   Note that awe and **beauty** are not the same things.

**Reasons to believe that beauty is universal** - 
 1. In some studies symmetrical facial feature was found to be more **attractive even to little children**
 2. A person with good attitude and personality seems more **beautiful** to all.
 3. Shape of some body parts e.g. chin-shape (prominent chin in male and rounded chin in female) and vertical forehead are things that most people consider to be a part of **beauty**.
 4. "It is hard to find a purely biological basis of beauty", when a cat looks at you, it becomes difficult to know whether it is expecting food or is fearful or just admiring your **beauty** !! Much of the feeling in animals are yet to discover and thus evidences are few till now on this aspect. So, most evidences and scientific studies that you find with universal beauty are actually on human species as a whole. Studies on body shapes are an example.
 5. But if we consider attraction between animals (other than that for mating purpose) to be an indicator of the feeling of beauty, then certain properties like risk taking behavior, fitness etc may be considered to be universally **beautiful**.

So, there is enough evidence to consider beauty as both subjective and universal feeling.

Feel free to criticize this answer in the comment section below...but please give evidence (examples) with it, so that it can be a collection of all different thoughts in this topic. Please write down any mistake in this answer as I have written it in a hurry !!

For further knowledge you may follow these two links -

http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20150622-the-myth-of-universal-beauty

https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/homo-consumericus/201004/beauty-culture-specific-or-universally-defined

Thank you all.

Comment: Wow I think this is a really good answer actually. I would have maybe liked a little more discussion about if it's a coincidence that what birds find attractive is what humans think is beautiful, because it seems across a huge array of bird species that where there isn't too much pressure to blend in with grasses or something, the male's way of attracting a female is by looking or sounding in a way we often consider nice or if there really is some kind of "beauty rule" applying there.